# Getting ERROR - Invalid value of sonar.sources for com.dummy.ABC:ABC-Test:Module2

Tags: sonarqube-5.0

### build.xml

```
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="com.dummy.ABC:ABC-Test" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="ABC-Test" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="**strong text**src" />

<property name="sonar.modules" value="Module1,Module2"/>        
<!-- Override some properties at module level -->
<property name="Module1.sonar.projectName" value="Module1"/>
<property name="Module1.sonar.modules" value="SubModule1,SubModule2"/>
<property name="SubModule1.sonar.projectName" value="Proj1"/>
<property name="Proj1.sonar.sources" value="src" />
<property name="SubModule2.sonar.projectName" value="Proj2"/>
<property name="Proj2.sonar.sources" value="src" />

<property name="Module2.sonar.projectName" value="Module2"/>
<property name="Module2.sonar.modules" value="SubModule1,SubModule2"/>
<property name="SubModule1.sonar.projectName" value="Proj1"/>
<property name="Proj1.sonar.sources" value="src" />
<property name="Proj1.sonar.tests" value="junit" />
<property name="SubModule2.sonar.projectName" value="Proj2"/>
<property name="Proj2.sonar.modules" value="InnerModule"/>
<property name="InnerModule.sonar.projectName" value="Proj3"/>
<property name="Proj3.sonar.sources" value="src"/>
```

### Console Output:

```
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.4.1
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file://lib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.1.jar
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\dummy\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] Load global repositories
[sonar:sonar] Load global repositories (done) | time=594ms
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\dummy\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] Load plugins index
[sonar:sonar] Load plugins index (done) | time=219ms
[sonar:sonar] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[sonar:sonar] Process project properties
[sonar:sonar] Invalid value of sonar.sources for com.dummy.ABC:ABC-   Test:Module2:Proj2

BUILD FAILED
E:\SecureAccessLink\SALEnterprise\trunk\SALEnterprise-Dev-  trunk\SALEnterprise\build.xml:500: java.lang.IllegalStateExcep
```

tion: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock
        at  org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The folder 'src' does not exist for 'com.dummy.ABC:ABC-Test:Module2
:Proj2' (base directory = E:\CodeBase\ABC-Test\Module2\Proj2)

Comment: I have mentioned 'sonar.sources' property at module level also,but that value is not taking, since it is taking global property only.